# Increasing the width of a 960px css grid

Tags: grid, css-frameworks, inuit.css

After sampling plenty css grids, i found love in the [inuit.css grid](https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css/blob/master/objects/_grids.scss) (especially the negative margin gutter technique), i only wish it was wider.

Due to my lack of in-depth knowledge in grids and responsive/adaptive web design i was wondering:

- Where should i start?
- What are the things i should take into consideration?

If i wanted to widen the grid (or create another grid?). I have a feeling its a little bit more than just changing the width value of the columns

Answer (score 0):

Several online grid system generators let you specify a new width and column number to regenerate the base style sheets. e.g. http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs01.php

Comment: i have seen them but my goal is to learn the things i should take into consideration when choosing the width of a grid as it relates to adaptive web design